# Best way to expose sitecore data to external system as web api

Tags: webapi

In sitecore 7.2 I had customized sitecore web api to expose data from sitecore to external system as API.

I am just wondering if something new/enhanced has been added in sitecore 8.2 to expose data from sitecore to external system.

Comment: I think you can try to use Sitecore Data Exchange Framework.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use Sitecore Client Services to expose data from Sitecore

`Sitecore.Services.Client` provides a service layer on both the server and the client side of Sitecore applications that you use to develop data-driven applications.

`Sitecore.Services.Client` is configurable and extendable, and the framework and scaffolding it provides help you create the client-server communication in an application in a consistent way. `Sitecore.Services.Client` uses the ASP.NET Web API as a foundation.

Links:
https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/91/sitecore-experience-manager/sitecore-services-client.html

https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/91/sitecore-experience-manager/sitecore-services-client-security.html

https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/92/sitecore-experience-manager/the-restful-api-for-the-itemservice.html

Comment: Thanks for the reponse. Links are helpful but I am not able to figure out how to use sitecore.service.client. If you can point me to sample code that will be great to start with.

Comment: Check this out: https://github.com/kevinobee/SSC.AggregateService

Comment: Technically for 8.2 the following link is correct for Sitecore.Services.Client. https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/82/sitecore-experience-platform/en/sitecore-services-client.html